# Error importing psycopg2 on M1 mac: incompatible architecture

Tags: python, macos, psycopg2, apple-m1

When I try importing psycopg2, I get this error message:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-310-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.5_3/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 37):

I had the same problem over some Postgres upgrade. Reinstalling `psycopg2-binary` solved the problem as it was a caching issue for me.

```
pip install psycopg2-binary --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir
```

Comment: both Utku's and cgl's solutions worked for me.  I tried both, this one is more to my liking.

Comment: Since my package was `psycopg2`,  `pip install psycopg2 --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir`
This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

For Mac M1 users;

```
pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
```

This will solve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/83#issuecomment-1232400894

```
ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/postgresql@14/* /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the package -x86_64:

```bash
arch -x86_64 python3 -pip uninstall psycopg2-binary
```

Install the package -arm64:

```bash
arch -arm64 python3 -m pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Comment: Avoid code only asnwer and provide an explanation.

Comment: I had to do it the other way around, but this works.