# Package imports not working within PyCharm Python console

Tags: pycharm, psycopg2, python-poetry

I am using Poetry for a project in Python 3.11. Any commands with `poetry run ...` work fine, but I am having issues when using the Poetry environment as a Python interpreter in PyCharm.

When I use the Python console and try to `import psycopg2`, I get

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psychopg2'

Running `poetry run python -c "import psycopg2"` in the terminal works fine. The interpreter configured in PyCharm is the one corresponding to the Poetry environment that I extract via `poetry env info -p`.

Interestingly, when running using the Poetry environment manually via:

```bash
/Users/richardknudsen/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app-v-qyCfCG-py3.11/bin/python -c "import psycopg2"
```

I get an error related to processor arch:

> ImportError:
> dlopen(/Users/richardknudsen/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app-v-qyCfCG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-311-darwin.so,
> 0x0002): tried:
> '/Users/richardknudsen/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app-v-qyCfCG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-311-darwin.so'
> (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need
> 'arm64')),
> '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/richardknudsen/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app-v-qyCfCG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-311-darwin.so'
> (no such file),
> '/Users/richardknudsen/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/app-v-qyCfCG-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-311-darwin.so'
> (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need
> 'arm64')

Both erros do not occur with all packages, e.g. importing `sqlalchemy` works fine.

I feel like I am missing some puzzle piece in understanding how poetry works to set it up properly in PyCharm.

Comment: Is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psychopg2' the original command output? If yes you have a typo (remove the h).

Comment: Did you activate the venv in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used PyCharm myself, but when using poetry I usually make poetry create a virtual environment inside my project by configuring poetry globally or using the following `poetry.toml` file in my project:

```ini
[virtualenvs]
create = true
in-project = true
```

The main benefit: With a local virtual environment it is much easier working with tools that do not support poetry or when the poetry integration has issues finding the right venv. If a tool does not support poetry it at least supports local venvs in a `.venv` folder.

Edit: It is also way easier to configure your tools because your local python interpreter is always located at `.venv/bin/python` and not at some randomly generated location.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the first problem. 

The second problem was actually a different one, this guide here helped me solve it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73625820/error-importing-psycopg2-on-m1-mac-incompatible-architecture

Comment: Oh, I forgot that part. There are not that many packages out there which compile on the users machine and psycopg2 is one of them. If you don't want to use the pre-compiled binaries and compile them on your machine instead, you need to download the python compilation headers (and maybe a C compiler?) on your machine. On most linux distributions this packages is called python3-dev, but I don't know how to install it on macOS/with homebrew.